# How to change Elasticsearch document source content by modifying Elasticsearch source code?

Tags: elasticsearch, encryption

I need to encrypt Elasticsearch document source content for security.

The final effect to be achieved is as follows:

input:

```
{
   "title":"you know, for search",
   "viewcount": 20
}
```

In es:

```
{
  "title": "zpv!lopx-!gps!tfbsdi",    // whatever, encrypted title
  "viewcount": ☯                      // whatever, encrypted viewcount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having encrypted data in ES, We can make communication between ES nodes and clients can be encrypted with X-Pack. That means If the Client is allowed to query the data in the end he will be able to get the data. We can control that with X-Pack.

Indexing encrypted data in ElasticSearch is not recommended IMO, since it involves additional overhead of Decrypting and encrypting the data.

Comment: I agree with your opinion. I'm experimenting at the expense of performance.